# Опция "Restore Ubuntu to factory state" Опасно?

Tags: grub, ubuntu

Что значит опция "Restore Ubuntu to factory state" в главном меню загрузчика GRUB на ноутбуке Dell (Африканка уже была установлена)? После её нажатия все файлы сотрутся и нужно всё заново настраивать?

Answer (score 1):

Не пытались перевести? Похоже, что не пытались. "Восстановление Ubuntu до заводского состояния". Скорее всего да (сотрутся), потому что заметил, что теперь производители создают где-то на харде образ исходного состояния диска, который и заливается на HDD по выбору сего пункта